# Adobe Flash 10 GPU and Adobe AIR for Android

Tags: android, flash, opengl, air, flash-cs5

How can i make the Augmented Reality applcation on Android mobile phone (HTC Nexus One) that i have developed using the flash platform faster, since flash doesnt support OpenGL for 3D graphics.

Can I make it faster using GPU Acceleration?

Or there is any way to combine Flash and OpenGL?

Any online sources talking about this subject will be very useful..

Please help me to understand if this is possible to be done.

Comment: flash on android? you just couldn't choose worse..

Comment: @fazo at least there is a way?:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this 3d engine: [Alternativa3D 8](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/). They provide GPU-accelerated 3D APIs. I haven't tried neither know the status of the project. They say it can/will run on Android.